# Can't transfer balance in polkadot.js.org?

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-node-template, runtime

I start running development node, and try to test about transfer balance in polkadot.js.org

Problem: `Make Transfer` button only hidden, not show

[image]

Comment: I don't know if `TUNIT` is smaller than `Unit`?

Comment: TUNIT > UNIT : Tera UNIT = 10^12 UNIT

Comment: How did you setup the node? Did you change the code?

Comment: I only run in development mode. I don't change anything.

Comment: Could you send us more information about how to replicate your issue? Are you running PolkadotJS locally?

Comment: I know the root of the cause. due to an incompatible version between polkadotjs api and my runtime version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew the reason:

The version of my runtime is not compatible with the latest Polkadot JS Explorer